# Simple push-pull problem

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, fet, piezo, push-pull

I've made a circuit based on the schematics below, which works fine at simulation. The goal is to add some extra oomph on the output of a LT1210 opa (V1) to drive a piezo element at higher voltages with square wave. V2 is a lab PSU with 300uF AE and 2uF cer-cap between GND and V+ (not drawn in schematic).

Since I'm driving the fet's in deep saturation the spec shouldn't have any influence as far as I can tell. Gate charges is below 20nC for both.

I get the same gate voltages as in simulation when reading the scope, but the output voltage is around 10 times lower than input.

Any thoughts? I suspect the answer to be fairly obvious..

[image: Schematic]

[image: Plot]

Comment: Your simulation is using the default NMOS and PMOS models, which are pseudo-idealized and do not accurately represent most real-world MOSFETs. What are you using when you build the circuit?

Comment: It is an odd circuit. Was it your intention to put PMOS on top and NMOS on bottom? Normally for a linear amplifier it would be the other way around. NMOS on top and PMOS on bottom, with sources connected together. Usually there would be split supplies. In simulation, I suggest that you also probe the drain currents of the two transistors to see if anything interesting is going on with that.

Comment: Since all you want to do is drive a piezo element, you will almost certainly be better off using a jellybean comparator such as the [LM211](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm311.pdf), which can drive 50mA directly from its open-collector output, and should be able to withstand 50V. Just make sure you stay within the input range.

Comment: At the very least, you should also add the LT1210 to your simulation. CFB op-amps do *not* like capacitive loads.

Comment: @CalebReister changing to real-world parts does not affect the circuit as they are well within saturation. The LM211 could be a thing to try. The push-pull output would give more voltage if needed though. The LT1210 is designed to drive capacitive loads.

Comment: @mkeith You're right. I put them like this to avoid split supplies. Drain currents have one peak each for the output transition, as expected.

Comment: I think you need to model it with accurate miller capacitance and gate-source capacitance if you are not already. It is all fine and good to say that it doesn't matter, but since your circuit is not working, you need to keep an open mind and try stuff.